# linux bash script running multiple python

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have 2 python scripts a.py and b.py
and I want to write a bash script that will load a.py and not run b.py until a.py is done doing it's thing.
simplistically

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python a.py
python b.py
```

but this is naive, a check to see if a.py is done... how do I do that?

Comment: That's the natural behavior, synchronous execution. If you wanted it otherwise (to run a in the background and immediately start b) you should append an ampersand & to the command, e.g. `python a.py&`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This by default will already run one after the other.

---

To check that `python a.py` completed successfully as a required condition for running `python b.py`, you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python a.py && python b.py
```

---

Conversely, attempt to run `python a.py`, and ONLY run 'python b.py' if `python a.py` did not terminate successfully:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python a.py || python b.py
```

---

To run them at the same time as background processes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python a.py &
python b.py &
```

---

(Responding to comment) - You can chain this for several commands in a row, for example:

```
python a.py && python b.py && python c.py && python d.py
```

Comment: can this be for more than two? if I also had c.py,`code` python a.py && python b.py && python c.py `code` or have to do another line for c.py separately? first `code` python a.py && python b.py`code` then `code`python b.py && python c.py`code`

Comment: Using the && it gives an error ./bash.sh: line 47: b.py: command not found  but it runs b.py if I have it as python b.py fine :(

Comment: @StudentOfScience that's if you were doing `python a.py && b.py` - can you show us what your script looks like and how you are invoking it?

Comment: Ok, dont mean to hijack the thread but its quite related. What if a.py logs something using the print command and based on the results, I would want to call b.py? I guess it would be best to check within a.py in order to call b.py?  The code being `x = ser.readline()
print "got '" + x + "'"` so then if AT+OK is received then call b.py.

Comment: what if I have for scripts: `parent.py`, `child1.py`,`child2.py`, `reunion.py`, I want `parent.py` to run first, then run `child1.py` and `child2.py` simultaneously, finally run `reunion.py` if both `child1.py` and `child2.py` are succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

```
prompt_err() {
```

`echo -e "\E[31m[ERROR]\E[m"`

`}`

`prompt_ok() {`

`echo -e "\E[32m[OK]\E[m"`

`}`

`status() {`

`if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then`

`prompt_ok`

`else`
    `prompt_err`

`exit -1`

`fi`

`}`

`a.py`

`status`

`b.py`

You can use the check code above.

If 'a.py' is done only then it will process 'b.py', otherwise it will exit with an 'Error'.

Comment: Most welcome ! You may also visit http://gettechgo.wordpress.com/2012/12/05/exit-status-shell-scripts/ to find more information.

Comment: @MansabUppal You *must* disclose whenever you link to your own website.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks :) Will keep a note !