# .sh to run two python files, One need the output of another

Tags: python, sh

I'm running into a question, there is data file I need to process, let's name it `Data.data`. I need to process this data file in two steps, each of them is in a separate python `.py` file.

The first step (Let's name it `first.py`) takes the `Data.data` as input and output into a `.txt` file named `output1.txt`(`output1.txt` is generated by `first.py`); then the second step (Let's name it `second.py`), takes the `output1.txt` as input and print the results.

Both python file take inputs with `sys.argv[1]`.

I'm trying to write a `.sh` file to do the job listed above (`Data.data`, `first.py` and `second.py` are in the same directory) --- first process `Data.data` with `first.py`, this should generate `output1.txt`, then run `second.py` with `output1.txt` as input and print the result with python's own `print` function.

Could anyone show me how to do this? I spent a lot of time trying to code this up and I'm really stucked. I can write a `.sh` that run 2 `.py` at the same time but not like this situation, please save me, thank you very much!

Comment: Can you show what have you done in code so far so it would be easy to point out where you're getting stuck?

Comment: Could you show us or elaborate what is in first.py and second.py? Is the reading/writing from output1.txt hardcoded, or do you want to have the filename as an argument?

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692519/linux-bash-script-running-multiple-python) will help.

I have tried doing it this way

I Created two files a.py and b.py

***a.py***

```
f= open("test.txt","w+")
for i in range(10):
 f.write("This is line %d\r\n" % (i+1))
f.close();
```

***b.py***

```
f=open("test.txt", "a+")
for i in range(2):
 f.write("Appended line %d\r\n" % (i+1))
f.close()
```

and then I have my shell script

***try.sh***

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python a.py && python b.py
```

it first creates the file as instructed in file a.py and then appends that file as instructed in file b.py.