# How to make Python package update within a code to take effect on-the-fly

Tags: python, pip

I have the following line of codes:

```
from pip import main as pipmain

# initial installation
pipmain(["install", "pyscenic==0.10.0"])
import pyscenic
pyscenic.__version__

# return 0.10.0
# Some large code here

# second installation
pipmain(["install", "install", "pyscenic==0.10.4"])
import pyscenic
pyscenic.__version__
# still return 0.10.0

# Another large chunk that required new version
```

There I want to upgrade the [pyscenic](https://github.com/aertslab/pySCENIC) package on-the-fly inside my code.
However as I noted above, in the second installation the version still doesn't change.
I expect it to change to 0.10.4. How can I do it properly?

I also tried this, still no avail:

```
import os
import importlib
os.system('pip install pyscenic==0.10.0')
import pyscenic
pyscenic.__version__
os.system('pip install pyscenic==0.10.4')
import pyscenic
pyscenic.__version__
importlib.reload(pyscenic)
pyscenic.__version__
```

All code tested on IPython (interactive).
If I exit the IPython and re-enter again it will take effect.
But that's not what I want.

Comment: You could maybe use `os.system('pip install pyscenic==0.10.4')` first tho `import os` and this works on windows, don't know about other OSs, this basically runs the given string in cmd

Comment: @Matiiss I tried that. The second `pyscenic.__version_` still gives 0.10.0

Comment: it could be that it takes a while for it to recognize the new version

Comment: @Matiiss as I stated above, I'd like it to take effect on-the-fly, so the next part of the code after that can use the version 0.10.4.

Comment: Even if you did dutifully `reload()` everything, it's still not guaranteed to be perfectly safe. I'd recommend just designing your system in a way that you can restart it after upgrading bits of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reloading submodules in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython) and/or [Reloading packages (and their submodules) recursively in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101895/reloading-packages-and-their-submodules-recursively-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to, a simple solution would be to write a bash file running sequentially two python files, with a change of version of the package pyscenic between the two python runs using pip. You can do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13692565/6193619), like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
pip install pyscenic==0.10.0
python first_script.py
pip install pyscenic==0.10.4
python second_script.py
```

Comment: this would better suit a comment not an answer

Comment: As stated in the help about comments, "Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post". I considered that my answer did neither of those, but instead proposed a way to solve scamander's problem. If you have more information about why my answer should be a comment, I would be happy to read it!

Comment: about comments this was written: Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated). However in the answer section it said this: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. So I guess Your post doesn't deserve a downvote really

Comment: @Erwan I tried that too, still doesn't work. Please post working example

Comment: That's very interesting, thank you for that, I agree that most of the information should be in the (attempted) answer, in the case of a broken link, I will add examples.

Comment: @scamander Which approach did you try, the `importlib` one?

Comment: @scamander Yes you are right, my bad, I thought this approach would work... I removed it from my answer. My best (and safest, given that playing with `reload` can lead to a whole load of problem) advice would be to run two python codes sequentially, with the package upgrade between the two runs, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

As several previous answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570635/installing-multiple-versions-of-a-package-with-pip), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308293/how-to-install-python-package-with-a-different-name-using-pip)) and [recent requests](https://discuss.python.org/t/installing-multiple-versions-of-a-package/4862) have mentioned, pip and Python weren't really designed with this in mind.

But with some clever hacking of Python's name system, and some knowledge of the package you want to work with, you could install two versions next to each other:

```sh
# Copyright © 2021 Alexander L. Hayes
# MIT License

git clone git@github.com:aertslab/pySCENIC pySCENIC100
git clone git@github.com:aertslab/pySCENIC pySCENIC104

(
  cd pySCENIC100
  git checkout 0.10.0
  sed -i "s/pyscenic/pyscenic100/g" setup.py
  sed -i "s/pyscenic/pyscenic100/g" MANIFEST.in
  sed -i "s/pyscenic/pyscenic100/g" setup.cfg
  (
    cd src
    mv pyscenic pyscenic100
    (
      cd pyscenic100
      sed -i "s/pyscenic/pyscenic100/g" binarization.py
      sed -i "s/pyscenic/pyscenic100/g" __init__.py
      sed -i "s/pyscenic/pyscenic100/g" _version.py
    )
  )
  python setup.py install
)

(
  cd pySCENIC104
  git checkout 0.10.4
  sed -i "s/pyscenic/pyscenic104/g" setup.py
  sed -i "s/pyscenic/pyscenic104/g" MANIFEST.in
  sed -i "s/pyscenic/pyscenic104/g" setup.cfg
  (
    cd src
    mv pyscenic pyscenic104
    (
      cd pyscenic104
      sed -i "s/pyscenic/pyscenic104/g" binarization.py
      sed -i "s/pyscenic/pyscenic104/g" __init__.py
      sed -i "s/pyscenic/pyscenic104/g" _version.py
      (
        cd cli
        sed -i "s/pyscenic/pyscenic104/g" *.py
      )
    )
  )
  python setup.py install
)
```

This bash script clones the repository twice, checks out versions `0.10.0` and `0.10.4`, does some renaming via `sed`, and finally installs two libraries named `pyscenic100` and `pyscenic104`:

```py
import pyscenic100
import pyscenic104

print(pyscenic100.__version__)
print(pyscenic104.__version__)
# 0.10.0+0.g3de37cb.dirty
# 0.10.4+0.g436561f.dirty
```

I don't know what happens during "`# Some large code here`", but it looks like examples from the documentation/tests work:

```py
from pyscenic100.featureseq import Feature as Feature100
from pyscenic104.featureseq import Feature as Feature104


f1 = Feature100.from_string('chr1 12 50 feature1 10.0 +')
f2 = Feature100.from_string('chr1 40 60 feature2 10.0 -')
print(f1.has_overlap_with(f2))
# True

f1 = Feature104.from_string('chr1 12 50 feature1 10.0 +')
f2 = Feature104.from_string('chr1 40 60 feature2 10.0 -')
print(f1.has_overlap_with(f2))
# True
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the preferred way to install packages, ie installing them within the scripts. Most of the packages even after updating have all the features that were in the older versions and since your version change is minor it shouldn't create a lot of issues.

However if you want to install packages within a script you can use `os.system` as you mentioned, but before installing the other version, first remove the previous version and you should be good to go.

If that doesn't solve your problem then you can look at this code. This should solve your problem of installing and uninstalling packages within a script.

```py
import subprocess
import sys

def install(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])

def uninstall(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "uninstall", package])
```

Do let me know if it works

Comment: This does nothing to update the version of the code which is running in the current script.

Comment: He can install package using ```install``` function specifying the exact version of the package and then later uninstall it using ```uninstall``` function and the install the other version of the same Package